# html add meta tag to header after page loaded

Tags: html, header, meta-tags, meta

I want to dynamically add a meta tag to my html header after the page is loaded. I found some solutions to add a meta tag, but the all only work while the page is loading. After the page is loaded once, the dont work anymore.

```
document.head.innerHTML += '<meta content="test" property="test"/>';
```

Thats what I tried. But as sayed above this does not work is the page is already loaded.

Is there a solution for this? Maybe something like reload the page?

Answer (score 1):

```
function ready() { 
    document.head.innerHTML += '<meta content="test" property="test"/>';
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Maybe event DOMContentLoaded is the solution, source: https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded.